# typscript compile API - change variable name

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I thought this would have been simple, just update a variable name. All the blogs/posts I find are adding/removing nodes. I simply want to update a variable name and output the `SourceFile`.

And I don't want to use ts-morph.

I've got my node ( a `NodeObject` in this case) but calling...

```
node.name.text = "testing";
```

Yields `Cannot set property text of #<IdentifierObject> which has only a getter`.

Is this possible? Do I have to use transformations? If so, a link to an example with an identifier name change would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

> I thought this would have been simple, just update a variable name.

That's why ts-morph exists. With the compiler API you will need to write a lot of code to do this, but with ts-morph you just need to do `ident.replaceWithText("newName")` or to rename with the language service use `ident.rename("newName")`.

To change the variable declaration's name identifier only, use the transformation API and then reprint out the AST to a string. So at a lower level, use the `factory.updateVariableDeclaration` function providing the existing variable declaration and then `factory.createIdentifier("yourNewIdentifierName")` for the `name` parameter. Afterwards, use the printer API to print it out as a string (see `ts.createPrinter()`).

If you wish to rename the variable declaration and all its usages then this is possible with the language service. First, write all the code to setup the language service, then use the `findRenameLocations` method to get all the rename locations and use the result to modify the text in place.